# Flattening one-to-many relationship in Django

Tags: python, django, list, flatten

I have a few model classes with basic one-to-many relationships.  For example, a book has many recipes, and each recipe has many ingredients:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Recipe(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
```

I'd like a flat list of all ingredients in all recipes from a particular book.  What's the best way to express this in Python?

If I was using LINQ, I might write something like this:

```
var allIngredients = from recipe in book.Recipes
                     from ingredient in recipe.Ingredients
                     select ingredient;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, it looks like there's a better approach using filter:

```
my_book = Book.objects.get(pk=1)
all_ingredients = Ingredient.objects.filter(recipe__book=my_book)
```

Comment: Well I suppose if you want to do it in the simple, one-line kind of way you could do this. ;)

Answer (score 1):

To print each recipe and its ingredients:

```
mybook = Book.objects.get(name="Jason's Cookbook")
for recipe in mybook.recipe_set.all():
    print recipe.name
    for ingredient in recipe.ingredients:
        print ingredient.text
```

And if you just want to get a list of all ingredient objects:

```
mybook = Book.objects.get(name="Jason's Cookbook")
ingredient_list = []
for recipe in mybook.recipe_set.all():
    for ingredient in recipe.ingredients:
        ingredient_list.append(ingredient)
```

[Documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects).

Comment: Hm, I'm not exactly looking to print the ingredients, but collect them into a list.  I'm imagining there's probably an idiom here that I'm missing.